# I am trying to achieve this query that doesn't show hazard insurance types

Tags: sql

I have this query written and I am trying to get all the records that don't equal 'HAZARD' as a property insurance type. However; When I run it Hazard records still show up.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
   ACD.MAJOR_TYPE AS "Major Type Cd"
 , ACD.MINOR_TYPE AS "Minor Type Cd"
 , ACD.ACCOUNT AS "Account Nbr"
 , ACD.OWNER_NAME AS "Owner Name"
 , ACD.CONTRACT_DATE AS "Contract Dt"
 , ACD.ORIG_BAL AS "Original Balance"
 ,INSTYPDESC

FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMONLOAN ACD

 WHERE ACD.CURR_DT = (SELECT MAX(CURR_DT) FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMON)
   AND UPPER(ACD.MINOR_TYPE) NOT IN ('7AP2','BSLC','CAIW','CSSF','PLFR','WCRS','WCRA','BSOF','BSOA','BSDF','BSLF','BSOL','BULA','BUFX','ACSF','ACSA','ACLF','ACFS','ACAS','7APP','XCLU','XLOC','WCAP','PLOC','PLOD','FFDU','CASF','PCFS','PCLD','PCUF','XCOL','XCLR','CMCF','CMCA','SFCF','SFCA','MFCF','MFCA','CSFX','CSAD','CCFX','CCAD')
   AND UPPER(ACD.ACCOUNT_STATUS) = 'ACT'
   AND ACD.ACCOUNT NOT IN 
         (SELECT ACCTNBR
          FROM EIS_DW.ACCTINSRECORDS
          WHERE EXPIREDATE IS NULL
             AND INSTYPDESC = 'HAZARD'
             AND PROD_DT = (SELECT MAX(CURR_DT) FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMON))

ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: For the one's showing up, do they have an EXPIREDATE? You have that limitation for your exclusion logic, as well as a date limitation. One or both reasons are likely the cause.

Comment: Should add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: SQL is all about relational and Boolean algebra. Your `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` subquery will return all account numbers whose expire date is null and whose insurance type description is 'HAZARD' and whose prod-date is the max date of a sub select. If a row in `ACCTINSRECORDS` is not of type 'HAZARD', it can still  be discarded from that sub select for having a non-null expire date or for having an older prod date. So its account number will not appear in the list for the `NOT IN()` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on number of records, I would pull everything that I possibly want into a CTE and then run an inner join, instead of running a NOT IN clause

```
With NotHazard as
(
    SELECT ACCTNBR
    FROM EIS_DW.ACCTINSRECORDS
    WHERE 
        EXPIREDATE IS NULL
        AND INSTYPDESC <> 'HAZARD'
        AND PROD_DT = (SELECT MAX(CURR_DT) FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMON)
)

SELECT 
   ACD.MAJOR_TYPE AS "Major Type Cd"
 , ACD.MINOR_TYPE AS "Minor Type Cd"
 , ACD.ACCOUNT AS "Account Nbr"
 , ACD.OWNER_NAME AS "Owner Name"
 , ACD.CONTRACT_DATE AS "Contract Dt"
 , ACD.ORIG_BAL AS "Original Balance"
 ,INSTYPDESC

FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMONLOAN ACD
INNER JOIN NotHazard H on ACD.ACCOUNT = H.ACCTNBR
 WHERE ACD.CURR_DT = (SELECT MAX(CURR_DT) FROM EIS_DW.ACCTCOMMON)
   AND UPPER(ACD.MINOR_TYPE) NOT IN ('7AP2','BSLC','CAIW','CSSF','PLFR','WCRS','WCRA','BSOF','BSOA','BSDF','BSLF','BSOL','BULA','BUFX','ACSF','ACSA','ACLF','ACFS','ACAS','7APP','XCLU','XLOC','WCAP','PLOC','PLOD','FFDU','CASF','PCFS','PCLD','PCUF','XCOL','XCLR','CMCF','CMCA','SFCF','SFCA','MFCF','MFCA','CSFX','CSAD','CCFX','CCAD')
   AND UPPER(ACD.ACCOUNT_STATUS) = 'ACT'

ORDER BY 3
```